# Showing that something is the zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that if the linear system of equations $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ cloumns, only has a solution when $b=0$ then $A$ is the zero-matrix.

My idea goes like this. Suppose $A$ isn't the zero matrix. Then there is an $x$ such that $b=Ax\neq 0$ so $Ax=b$ has a solution where $b\neq 0$ which is a contradiction.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: It looks fine yet you should probably be more concrete and say *what* $\;x\;$ is there s.t. $\;Ax\neq 0\;$ . You don't even need to check different cases, just to use the meaning of $\;A\neq 0\;$ .